# Pandas cut or groupby a date range

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple dataframes with a date column. I want to groupby these dataframes by the date column by 5 days. Normally something like this works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2016-11-01 09:21:07', 10], ['2016-09-14 02:46:01', 21], ['2016-08-11 03:26:33', 14], ['2016-10-17 14:20:44', 14]], 
                columns=['DateCol', 'Values'])
df['DateCol'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateCol'])

df.set_index('DateCol').groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('5D')).mean()
```

However, when I use `pd.TimeGrouper` it creates groups based on the dataframe I apply it to. If I do this on two different dataframes it yields different groups.
I want to group multiple dataframes by the same groups.

I tried using `pd.cut` but it doesn't work with datetime columns. `pd.cut(df['DateCol'], 10)` gives me `TypeError`.

Ideally I want to do something like this:

```
pd.groupby(df, pd.cut(df['DateCol'], pd.date_range(start='1/1/2016', end='1/1/2017', freq='5D')))
```

In other words, I need to groupby my dataframe by a specific date range.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you need to have all dataframes share the same set of dates. So, consider an outer merge on a distinct dataframe of dates to keep all columns. Outer merge keeps values in left and right joins and will fill `NaN` for corresponding dates not in current datframe. Then, run the `TimeGrouper`.

Below saves all dataframes to a list which is easier to run full operations on and avoids multiple objects in global environment:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'DateCol': [dt.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for i in 
                                ['2016-11-01 09:21:07', '2016-09-14 02:46:01',
                                 '2016-08-11 03:26:33', '2016-10-17 14:20:44']], 
                    'Values': [10, 21, 14, 14]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'DateCol': [dt.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for i in 
                                ['2016-07-28 13:56:19', '2016-03-07 06:23:48',
                                 '2016-09-26 05:31:10', '2016-08-03 12:02:59']], 
                    'Values': [7, 19, 28, 36]})    
dfs = [df1, df2]
alldates = pd.concat([i[['DateCol']] for i in dfs]).drop_duplicates()

for i in range(len(dfs)):
    dfs[i] = dfs[i].merge(alldates, on='DateCol', how='outer')    
    dfs[i] = dfs[i].set_index('DateCol').groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('5D')).mean()
    print(dfs[i].head())

#                      Values
# DateCol                    
# 2016-03-07 06:23:48     NaN
# 2016-03-12 06:23:48     NaN
# 2016-03-17 06:23:48     NaN
# 2016-03-22 06:23:48     NaN
# 2016-03-27 06:23:48     NaN
#                      Values
# DateCol                    
# 2016-03-07 06:23:48    19.0
# 2016-03-12 06:23:48     NaN
# 2016-03-17 06:23:48     NaN
# 2016-03-22 06:23:48     NaN
# 2016-03-27 06:23:48     NaN
```